# Rename a text file using batch or VBS

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I need to rename a text file using either a batch file or a vbscript. The format of the txt file is received as A353XXXXXXXX.txt and I need it to be renamed to simply A353.txt. The X's are never the same but the A353 is always the same. All scripts that I have tried are not executing properly. I need it to rename the file by the first four characters of the file name. It seems easy but it is giving me fits for some reason.

Comment: You could show us what you tried - we don't just deliver code here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7363523/69820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename using:

```
ren A353*.txt A353.txt
```

Comment: Of course, I am assuming you will move any previous "A353.txt" before you execute this command so that you don't get a "duplicate file" error

Comment: Interesting... are you executing the command after changing directory to the same folder as the file? It works for me at my end.

Comment: Sorry to just now get back to you. I tried it one my computer at home and everything worked just fine. weird. I will have to take a look and see what I was doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
Set var=A353xxxxxxxx.txt
ECHO %var%
Set var=%var:~0,4%.txt
ECHO %var%
PAUSE
move "A353xxxxxxxx.txt" "%var%"
```

We can iterate this over many files with a for loop as well.