# Batch File or vbscript that completes multiple tasks

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I am looking to do some automating on some imports. I am looking for a way to call multiple scripts to run from either one batch file or vbscript. what I am trying to do is the following:                               1) rename a file which is done in batch
                                         2) Move the renamed file to another folder
                                         3) Replace specified text within the file
                                         4) Rename the file with a date extension
I want to be able to schedule 1 batch file to run and handle all of these tasks from that 1 batch file. I have already written vbscripts to replace text, and move the file when done. Here is what I have so far which is done inside batch. Here is what I have so far which may help you understand what I mean.

(inside the batch file)

```
            cd C:\NEW
            ren A353*.txt A353.txt
   (step 2) cscript move1.vbs (which moves the file)
   (step 3) cscript TextReplace.vbs (which replaces a string of text in the A353.txt)
   (step 4) I need a script that will rename A353.txt to the month and date in this format MMDD. EX: A3530823.txt.
```

Comment: Why mix batch and VBScript? Why not just use VBScript?

Comment: I havent been able to figure out how to incorporate all of the steps within 1 vbscript.

Comment: I am also not sure how to rename 1 single text file with a vbs

Comment: FYI.... I am a noob lol.

Comment: Okay... Have you tried typing "rename file VBScript" in your favourite search engine?

Comment: I have finnnnally figured out a way to run all of the steps I need out of 1 VBS. I had the syntax wrong earlier. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mixing batch and VBScript, I recommend you just put all those tasks in a single VBScript. Here's an example of how to rename a file in VBScript.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.MoveFile "C:\MyFile.txt", "C:\YourFile.txt"
' Can continue to use FSO for other operations...
```

Please note that moving is essentially the same thing as renaming.

If you clarify what else you want, then more help will be forthcoming.

Comment: Thanks for the code! I have finnnnally figured out a way to run all of the steps I need out of 1 VBS. I had the syntax wrong earlier. Thanks everyone.